# How to remove App Store account on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, ios

I am using an iPad 4 with iOS 8.1. I have logged out from another Apple account and logged in using another email address. However, the App Store keeps asking me for the password of the old account (showing its email and there is no way to change it). I have done a full reboot but no help.

How do I completely remove this account from the iPad App Store?
My dad seems to have the same problem with his iPhone 6, and what he did was restore factory settings. That will take me lots of time so I only consider it as last option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there's a little confusion. Let me elaborate a little bit... I used to be a Senior Advisor for Apple and this was by far the most common call.

First, migrating to a new Apple ID can be difficult, but you can do it. To make sure all future purchases ask for your *new* Apple ID, go to Settings > iTunes & App Store and then select your Apple ID. Is this your new one or your old one? If it's your old one, tap "Sign Out" and try signing in with your new one. All future purchases should then prompt you for your **new** Apple ID and password.

However, keep in mind that **any apps that you've already downloaded with your old Apple ID** will prompt you for that old Apple ID and password when the apps need to be updated. (This is what everyone else is talking about). In order to never see or think about that old Apple ID again, you'll need to delete those apps over time and re-purchase them on your *new* Apple ID.

Second, it is imperative that you understand what email addresses are and aren't associated with each Apple ID. To check this out, go to id.apple.com and sign in to each of them. It is possible to have multiple emails associated with an Apple ID. It is also possible to have an "alternate Apple ID," which basically means you can use either to sign in.

One more thing—with the announcement of iOS 8, Apple IDs can be conjoined or paired using Family Sharing. It may just be more confusing, but check out the synopsis on Apple's website [here](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/?cid=wwa-us-kwg-features-com).

Answer (score 1):

This is because some of the currently installed apps on the device are installed with the old Apple ID. You need to uninstall these apps and reinstall them with the new Apple ID.

Comment: and how do I do that? Currently whenever I install a new app, it asks for my old account password. If I remove all the old apps, will App Store use my new account? I cant figure out why Apple doesnt have an easier option

Comment: Delete them from the phone; buy them again in iTunes whilst signed into your new account. Sync.